# Are there any issues to change Opencart page code from the admin panel?

Tags: opencart, e-commerce, admin, panel, cart

i am working in Opencart 3.0.2.2 and i want to make change in the code of some of pages from the admin panel ,so are there any issues that can a face later if i make this changes?? .As well as , if i try to change the code of some extension page does that will let me face problem in my website?

Comment: If you wiling to get some answer you should place your code here. No one has a telepathic ability to know in advance what changes you will make...

Answer (score 0):

While we test on opencart version 3.0.3.2,

- we were able to edit only the default template/twig, if we activate another theme still we keep on seeing the default theme’s template files in the theme editor, so it does not work for other themes. So, if you are using the default theme then you can make the code changes directly from the admin.
- Another rare issue you may face is while using OCMOD file, some OCMOD target codes so if you change from the theme editor then OCMOD may not find the right lines of code.
- Theme editor is for only twig files so you cannot change the logic of the extensions. If you change the twig file of the extensions then one issue you will face is while upgrading.

[Theme editor in Opencart](https://webocreation.com/blog/administrator-theme-editor-in-opencart-3-0-2-0-default-theme/)